# How can I wrap just a part of an element’s content using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I wrap a part of a content when I have elements and normal text? I've tried `.after()` but this automaticaly adds a closing tag.

I have got this:

```
<div class="block">
    <a href="#">example 1</a>
    .
    <a href="#">example 1</a>
    .
    <a href="#">example 1</a>
    .
    <a href="#">example 1</a>
</div>
```

And I have to transform it to:

```
<div class="block">
    <a href="#">example 1</a>
    <div class="wrap">
        .
        <a href="#">example 1</a>
        .
        <a href="#">example 1</a>
        .
        <a href="#">example 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.block').contents().filter(function(){
   return $(this).index() > 0;
}).wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uhzsN/

Answer (score 0):

The others answers are much clearer while this gives you some spesificity

```
var target = $($(".block a").slice(1)); // drop 1st
var container = $("<div class='wrap' />");
container.insertBefore($(target[0]));
target.each(function () {
    $(this).appendTo(container);
});
```

Comment: I think, This would wrap `div class="wrap"` on every targets.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.block a:gt(0)').wrapAll('<div class="wrap" />');
```